# Parsing Youtube video feed XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, youtube

So I am trying to make a script that gets the most recent video uploaded to my youtube channel. here is i what I have so far...

```
<body onLoad="loadVids()">
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc(channel)
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {
              xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {
              xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xhttp.open("GET","https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+channel+"/uploads/",false);
            xhttp.send();
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

        function loadVids() {
            var xml = loadXMLDoc("CHANNELNAME");


        }


    </script>
```

Now that I have loaded the XML how do I get each video uploaded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally for doing javascript parsing json data is much easier, youtube provides json data api. Here is the example of how to get video details using youtube json data api.

```
function loadVideosJson(channelName, callback) {
    $.getJSON("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+channelName+"/uploads?v=2&alt=json", callback)
}

function onVideoLoad(data) {
    var entries = data.feed.entry;
    for (i=0 ; i<entries.length; i++ ) {
        //Title
        console.log(data.feed.entry[i].title["$t"]);
        //Video thumbnail 
        console.log(data.feed.entry[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url);
        //Like that you can parse through json to get different attributes of video.
    }

}
//Call above functions using
loadVideosJson("bbc", onVideoLoad);
```